# Docker Folder Permission - Tar Error - Permission Error

Tags: docker

When I run `sudo docker run hello-world`, the following error shows up while pulling:

`docker: failed to register layer: Error processing tar file(exit status 1): permission denied. See 'docker run --help'.`

Checking the permission of the docker folder, it looks like this:

```
drwx------ 5 root root 4096 Mar  6 15:31 aufs
drwx------ 2 root root 4096 Mar  6 15:31 builder
drwx------ 4 root root 4096 Mar  6 15:31 buildkit
drwx------ 3 root root 4096 Mar  6 15:31 containerd
drwx------ 2 root root 4096 Mar  6 15:31 containers
drwx------ 3 root root 4096 Mar  6 15:31 image
drwxr-x--- 3 root root 4096 Mar  6 15:31 network
drwx------ 4 root root 4096 Mar  6 15:31 plugins
drwx------ 2 root root 4096 Mar  6 15:58 runtimes
drwx------ 2 root root 4096 Mar  6 15:31 swarm
drwx------ 2 root root 4096 Mar  6 16:13 tmp
drwx------ 2 root root 4096 Mar  6 15:31 trust
drwx------ 2 root root 4096 Mar  6 15:31 volumes
```

Does it look right to have the listed permission above? It is a `Architecture: ppc64le` server and docker was installed following the official documentation.

For the error, would `chmod` this folder help?

Thank you.

Comment: please share your Dockerfile :)

Comment: @cousine There is no dockerfile, I was just doing a docker pull

Comment: the permissions look correct, my guess would be something messed up in docker's workspace, have you tried reinstalling docker?

Comment: @cousine thanks for letting me know! I tried once, it gives me the same error